# How to upload a file using REST and C#

Tags: rest, onedrive-for-business

I already go a connection with the OAuth 2.0 protocol.
I am using REST and C# to get file- and folder information, create folders etc. through WinForms.

Im not able to upload a picture. (A text file I can upload but when I try to upload a picture I can't open it in OneDrive for Business) 
This is what I got now:

```
public void CreateFile(string folderPath, string fileName, bool overwrite, byte[] data)
{
    string strData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    string parameters = strData;

    string strOverwrite = overwrite.ToString().ToLower();
    string response = HttpPostWithAccessToken(this.ServiceUri + "/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderPath + "')/Files/Add(url='" + fileName + "', overwrite=" + strOverwrite + ")", parameters);
}
```

The method to upload the data:

```
private string HttpPostWithAccessToken(string uri, string parameters)
{
    // Set settings
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("client-request-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

    // Set the parameters
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        writer.Write(parameters);
    }

    // Get the response
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

How to get this working with images as well?

Comment: this.ServiceUri contains "_api/" ?

Comment: try remove encoding, because you are working with image and not text.

Comment: and other, when object is a image or vudeo use BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 2):

Better later then never, apparently you should not convert byte array into string via [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx):

```
string strData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

and then convert it back:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
```

In fact that's the reason why uploaded picture is getting corrupted. See Jon Skeet [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997022/1375553):

> You should absolutely not use an Encoding to convert arbitrary binary
>   data to text. Encoding is for when you've got binary data which
>   genuinely is encoded text - this isn't.

But in your case there is no need to convert byte array, instead use [`Stream.Write Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) to write byte array into stream:

```
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

**Modified example**

```
    public static void CreateFile(string serviceUrl, string accessToken, string folderUrl, string fileName, bool overwrite, byte[] data)
    {
        var sOverwrite = overwrite.ToString().ToLower();
        var formDigestVal = RequestFormDigest(serviceUrl); //FormDigestValue is required for POST method
        HttpPostWithAccessToken(serviceUrl + "/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')/Files/Add(url='" + fileName + "', overwrite=" + sOverwrite + ")", accessToken, formDigestVal,  data);
    }


    private static string HttpPostWithAccessToken(string url,string accessToken, string formDigestValue, byte[] data)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest",formDigestValue);

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```